# Agregar elementos desde una lista a un diccionario en Python

Tags: python, diccionarios

Verán,necesito a partir de una lista rescatar algunos campos para armar un diccionario , la estructura de lista que poseo es algo asi:

```
[
        {
            "id": 11,
            "type": "base",
            "metadata": {
                "carId": 10078,
                "displayName": "Mazda"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 70,
            "type": "other",
            "metadata": {
                "carId": 10079,
                "displayName": "Subaru"
            }
        }
]
```

Actualmente en mi código estoy realizando lo siguiente:

```
info = {}


for key in list_one:
    info['carId'] = key['metadata']['carId']
    info['displayName'] = key['metadata']['displayName']
```

pero como resultado obtengo un diccionario solo con una llave y un valor , no todos los elementos del arreglo.

alguíen puede indicarme que es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a stackoverflow. ¿Podrías, por favor, proporcionar un ejemplo del resultado que necesitas?

Comment: ```python3
list_one = [...]
info = {}
for key in list_one:
    info['carId'] = key['metadata']['carId']
    info['displayName'] = key['metadata']['displayName']
print(info)
``` y me ha funcionado correctamente, de hecho me da el siguiente output: `{'carId': 10079, 'displayName': 'Subaru'}`, nota lo hice con el siguiente comando: `python3 ./NOMBRE.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un diccionario (que es lo que estás construyendo) no puede contener claves repetidas. Por tanto cuando asignas por segunda vez algo a la misma clave, sobreescribes lo que había antes.

Entiendo que lo que querrías es una de estas dos opciones:

- Que cada clave en el diccionario almacene al final una *lista* con los valores que irían a esa clave.
- O bien que en vez de un diccionario la estructura final que quieres obtener sea una lista de diccionarios.

### Primera opción

Es sencilla de construir si usas un `defaultdict(list)` pues en este tipo de diccionarios si intentas acceder a una clave que no existía previamente, se creará una nueva con un valor de tipo `list` (vacía), a la que puedes ir agregando cosas con `.append()`.

Entonces el código sería así:

```
from collections import defaultdict

info = defaultdict(list)

for key in list_one:
    info['carId'].append(key['metadata']['carId'])
    info['displayName'].append(key['metadata']['displayName'])
```

El resultado de procesar tus datos de ejemplo con este enfoque sería:

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'carId': [10078, 10079], 'displayName': ['Mazda', 'Subaru']})
```

### Segunda opción

En este caso en cada iteración del bucle creas un nuevo diccionario y lo añades a la lista resultado:

```
info = []

for key in list_one:
  info.append({
      "cardId": key['metadata']['carId'],
      "displayName": key['metadata']['displayName']
      })
```

En este caso el resultado en `info` sería:

```
[{'cardId': 10078, 'displayName': 'Mazda'},
 {'cardId': 10079, 'displayName': 'Subaru'}]
```

Comment: muchas gracias por la explicación amigo!!

Answer (score 0):

Estás sobreescribiendo en cada caso la key del diccionario, por eso solamente tienes como resultado un solo `key` => `value`.

No sé exáctamente cómo necesitas que sea la `key` pero, lo que tienes que evitar es que se repita para que puedas seguir añadiendo elementos.

Un ejemplo:

```
list_one = [
        {
            "id": 11,
            "type": "base",
            "metadata": {
                "carId": 10078,
                "displayName": "Mazda"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 70,
            "type": "other",
            "metadata": {
                "carId": 10079,
                "displayName": "Subaru"
            }
        }
]

info = {}

counter = 0

for key in list_one:
    # Ya que no se puede repetir la key, quiero que las keys se vayan incrementando, e.g:
    # carId_0, carId_1, carId2, ...
    # Usamos el contador (es solo un ejemplo), para no tener la misma key repetida 
    info[f"carId_{counter}"] = key['metadata']['carId']
    # Aumentamos el contador en cada iteración
    counter += 1

print(info)
```

Resultado:

```
$ -> python3 test.py 
{'carId_0': 10078, 'carId_1': 10079}
```

Answer (score 0):

Los diccionarios no trabajan así en Python, por lo que veo no necesitas hacer un diccionario, más bien un listado de diccionarios, por ejemplo te recomendaría hacer los diccionarios con tus card_id y tu display_name

```
info = []

for key in list_one:
    nuevo_diccionario = {}
    nuevo_diccionario['carId'] = key['metadata']['carId']
    nuevo_diccionario['displayName'] = key['metadata']['displayName']
    info.append(nuevo_diccionario)

for i in info:
    print(i)
```

Retorna:

```
{'carId': 10078, 'displayName': 'Mazda'}
{'carId': 10079, 'displayName': 'Subaru'}
```

Aunque, te recomendaría hacer el diccionario con tu carId como clave y tu displayName como valor, en ese caso, si quieres retornar esto (que es más "lindo"):

```
[{10078: 'Mazda'}, {10079: 'Subaru'}]
```

Sería algo como:

```
info = []
for key in list_one:
    nuevo_diccionario = {
        key['metadata']['carId']: key['metadata']['displayName']
    }
    info.append(nuevo_diccionario)

pprint(info)
```